# Google maps streetview tiles do not load in Firefox initially, only after dragging

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap, google-street-view

I have a problem with google maps streetview (in a bootstrap theme, if that has something to do with it).

I set the streetview visible with a click of a button and it works in IE and Chrome ok, but in Firefox, the streetview stays gray (ie. it doesn't load the initial tiles) until you drag the view with a mouse.

I created a fiddle about it, try your self and be amazed:

http://jsfiddle.net/wK5Hq/22/

Anyone have a guess why is this happening?

EDIT: Now when I tried it in the fiddle, the tiles are not loading at all with Firefox, loads fine on chrome. In my real environment, the tiles load in Firefox too after first drag of the view.

EDIT2: The tiles didn't show at all in the fiddle because I had forgot to add the styles to fix bootstrap messing with the google map canvas. I added ".map-canvas img" rule to the css and now it shows the initial problem. Tiles wont load until street view is dragged in Firefox. Updated the fiddle link above.

Here's the code from the fiddle

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Google maps streeview issue - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">



      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.11&sensor=false&foo=.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    @import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.map-canvas img {
    border: none !important;
    max-width: none !important;
}

.panorama-activated-map-canvas {
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

.panorama-activated-panorama-canvas {
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.panorama-disabled-map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

.panorama-disabled-panorama-canvas {
  display: none;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var data = "{success:true, data:{\"schoolMarker\":{\"lat\":62.759379214514,\"lng\":22.840391666132},\"polylines\":[{\"path\":[{\"lat\":62.768091219265,\"lng\":22.841507465082},{\"lat\":62.767678823231,\"lng\":22.841421634393},{\"lat\":62.767168229676,\"lng\":22.841292888361},{\"lat\":62.766569252889,\"lng\":22.840928107935},{\"lat\":62.765842608979,\"lng\":22.840456039148},{\"lat\":62.76528288457,\"lng\":22.839919597345},{\"lat\":62.764772249527,\"lng\":22.839576274591},{\"lat\":62.764340166815,\"lng\":22.839533359247},{\"lat\":62.764016100627,\"lng\":22.839490443903},{\"lat\":62.763623288351,\"lng\":22.839554816919},{\"lat\":62.762660876165,\"lng\":22.839919597345},{\"lat\":62.761885031233,\"lng\":22.840220004755},{\"lat\":62.761020774875,\"lng\":22.840498954492},{\"lat\":62.760303815724,\"lng\":22.840820819574},{\"lat\":62.759655591079,\"lng\":22.841035396295},{\"lat\":62.759439513032,\"lng\":22.840541869836}]}]}}";
var map = null;
var schoolmarker = null;
var polyBounds = null;
var panorama = null;
var streetViewService = null;
var g = google.maps;
var response = eval( "(" + data + ")" );
if (response.success) {
    initMap('#map_canvas', '#panorama_canvas', response.data);
}
function initMap(mapSelector, panoramaSelector, data) {
    var mapOptions = {
      scrollwheel: false,
      zoom: 5,
      minZoom: 5,
      streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [g.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, g.MapTypeId.SATELLITE]
      },
      center: new g.LatLng(65.567, 25.303),
      mapTypeId: g.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      draggableCursor: 'auto',
      draggingCursor: 'move',
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
      scaleControl: true
    };
    map = new g.Map($(mapSelector).get(0), mapOptions);
    mapSelector = null;
    mapOptions = null;

    schoolmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      animation: g.Animation.DROP,
      draggable: true,
      icon: 'http://www.mapsmarker.com/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/dancinghall.png',
      map: map,
      position: new g.LatLng(data.schoolMarker.lat, data.schoolMarker.lng)
    });

    polyBounds = new g.LatLngBounds();
    $.each(data.polylines, function(index, polyline) {
        var path = [];
        $.each(polyline.path, function(index, position) {
            var point = new g.LatLng(position.lat, position.lng);
            polyBounds.extend(point);
            path.push(point);
        });
        var polyLineObj = new g.Polyline({
            strokeColor: "#00BA03",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 4,
            path: path,
            clickable: false
        });
        polyLineObj.setMap(map);
    });
    map.fitBounds(polyBounds);
    map.setCenter(schoolmarker.getPosition());

    panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama($(panoramaSelector).get(0));
    panorama.setVisible(false);
    streetViewService = new g.StreetViewService();
    map.setStreetView(panorama);
  }

$('#thebutton').click(function () {
    $('#map_canvas').removeClass('panorama-disabled-map-canvas').addClass('panorama-activated-map-canvas');
    $('#panorama_canvas').removeClass('panorama-disabled-panorama-canvas').addClass('panorama-activated-panorama-canvas');
    g.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.fitBounds(polyBounds);
    map.setCenter(schoolmarker.getPosition());
    streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(schoolmarker.getPosition(), 50, function(panoramaData, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
            var heading = g.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(panoramaData.location.latLng, schoolmarker.getPosition());

            var panoOptions = {
                position: panoramaData.location.latLng,
                addressControl: false,
                linksControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                style: g.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            pov: {
                heading: heading,
                pitch: 10,
                zoom: 2
            },
            enableCloseButton: false,
            visible:true
            };
            panorama.setOptions(panoOptions);
            g.event.trigger(panorama, 'resize');
        }
    });
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container" id="infocontainer" style=""><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="thebutton" onclick="return false;">Click here</a></div>        
  <div id="mapcontainer" class="container" style="position: relative">
    <div class="container hero-unit" style="padding:0;">
                <div class="map-canvas panorama-disabled-map-canvas" id="map_canvas" style="height: 480px;"></div>
        <div class="map-canvas panorama-disabled-panorama-canvas" id="panorama_canvas" style="height: 480px;"></div>
    </div>      
  </div>
  <div id="bottomcontainer" style="">        

  </div>      
  <div id="log"></div>    
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it resolved.

It started to work when I added initial position to the street view when creating it for the first time.

See fixed code in fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wK5Hq/23/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Google maps streeview issue - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">



      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.11&sensor=false&foo=.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    @import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.map-canvas img {
    border: none !important;
    max-width: none !important;
}

.panorama-activated-map-canvas {
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

.panorama-activated-panorama-canvas {
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.panorama-disabled-map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

.panorama-disabled-panorama-canvas {
  display: none;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
var data = "{success:true, data:{\"schoolMarker\":{\"lat\":62.759379214514,\"lng\":22.840391666132},\"polylines\":[{\"path\":[{\"lat\":62.768091219265,\"lng\":22.841507465082},{\"lat\":62.767678823231,\"lng\":22.841421634393},{\"lat\":62.767168229676,\"lng\":22.841292888361},{\"lat\":62.766569252889,\"lng\":22.840928107935},{\"lat\":62.765842608979,\"lng\":22.840456039148},{\"lat\":62.76528288457,\"lng\":22.839919597345},{\"lat\":62.764772249527,\"lng\":22.839576274591},{\"lat\":62.764340166815,\"lng\":22.839533359247},{\"lat\":62.764016100627,\"lng\":22.839490443903},{\"lat\":62.763623288351,\"lng\":22.839554816919},{\"lat\":62.762660876165,\"lng\":22.839919597345},{\"lat\":62.761885031233,\"lng\":22.840220004755},{\"lat\":62.761020774875,\"lng\":22.840498954492},{\"lat\":62.760303815724,\"lng\":22.840820819574},{\"lat\":62.759655591079,\"lng\":22.841035396295},{\"lat\":62.759439513032,\"lng\":22.840541869836}]}]}}";
var map = null;
var schoolmarker = null;
var polyBounds = null;
var panorama = null;
var streetViewService = null;
var g = google.maps;
var response = eval( "(" + data + ")" );
if (response.success) {
    initMap('#map_canvas', '#panorama_canvas', response.data);
}
function initMap(mapSelector, panoramaSelector, data) {
    var mapOptions = {
      scrollwheel: false,
      zoom: 5,
      minZoom: 5,
      streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [g.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, g.MapTypeId.SATELLITE]
      },
      center: new g.LatLng(65.567, 25.303),
      mapTypeId: g.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      draggableCursor: 'auto',
      draggingCursor: 'move',
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
      scaleControl: true
    };
    map = new g.Map($(mapSelector).get(0), mapOptions);
    mapSelector = null;
    mapOptions = null;

    schoolmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      animation: g.Animation.DROP,
      draggable: true,
      icon: 'http://www.mapsmarker.com/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/dancinghall.png',
      map: map,
      position: new g.LatLng(data.schoolMarker.lat, data.schoolMarker.lng)
    });

    polyBounds = new g.LatLngBounds();
    $.each(data.polylines, function(index, polyline) {
        var path = [];
        $.each(polyline.path, function(index, position) {
            var point = new g.LatLng(position.lat, position.lng);
            polyBounds.extend(point);
            path.push(point);
        });
        var polyLineObj = new g.Polyline({
            strokeColor: "#00BA03",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 4,
            path: path,
            clickable: false
        });
        polyLineObj.setMap(map);
    });
    map.fitBounds(polyBounds);
    map.setCenter(schoolmarker.getPosition());

    streetViewService = new g.StreetViewService();
    streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(schoolmarker.getPosition(), 50, function(panoramaData, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
            var heading = g.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(panoramaData.location.latLng, schoolmarker.getPosition());

            var panoOptions = {
                position: panoramaData.location.latLng,
                addressControl: false,
                linksControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                style: g.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            pov: {
                heading: heading,
                pitch: 10,
                zoom: 2
            },
            enableCloseButton: false,
            visible:false
            };
            panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama($(panoramaSelector).get(0), panoOptions);
        }
    });
    map.setStreetView(panorama);
  }

$('#thebutton').click(function () {
    $('#map_canvas').removeClass('panorama-disabled-map-canvas').addClass('panorama-activated-map-canvas');
    $('#panorama_canvas').removeClass('panorama-disabled-panorama-canvas').addClass('panorama-activated-panorama-canvas');
    g.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.fitBounds(polyBounds);
    map.setCenter(schoolmarker.getPosition());
    streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(schoolmarker.getPosition(), 50, function(panoramaData, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
            var heading = g.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(panoramaData.location.latLng, schoolmarker.getPosition());

            var panoOptions = {
                position: panoramaData.location.latLng,
                addressControl: false,
                linksControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                style: g.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            pov: {
                heading: heading,
                pitch: 10,
                zoom: 2
            },
            enableCloseButton: false,
            visible:true
            };
            panorama.setOptions(panoOptions);
            g.event.trigger(panorama, 'resize');
        }
    });
});
});//]]>

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container" id="infocontainer" style=""><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="thebutton" onclick="return false;">Click here</a></div>
  <div id="mapcontainer" class="container" style="position: relative">
    <div class="container hero-unit" style="padding:0;">
                <div class="map-canvas panorama-disabled-map-canvas" id="map_canvas" style="height: 480px;"></div>
        <div class="map-canvas panorama-disabled-panorama-canvas" id="panorama_canvas" style="height: 480px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomcontainer" style="">

  </div>
  <div id="log"></div>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Sometimes StreetView worked and at other times it just displayed grey.

It depended on the location.

Let me clarify the solution...

My unreliable code was like this:

```
function showStreetView(lat, lng)
{
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    var panoramaOptions =
    {
        position: pos,
        pov: {
            heading: 0,
            pitch: 0
        }
    };

    var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

    var STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE = 100;

    streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(pos, STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE, function(streetViewPanoramaData, status)
    {
        if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK)
        {
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('streetView'), panoramaOptions);

            map.setStreetView(panorama);
        }
        else
        {
            // no street view available in this range, or some error occurred
            map.getStreetView().setVisible(false);
        }
    });
}
```

... that is, the 'panoramaOptions' were near the beginning and contained the position that I calculated.

I changed this to put the 'panoramaOptions' after the call to streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation() and set the position within it to the value returned in 'streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng' i.e. the actual position of the panorama, not my calculated position. Then it worked.

The updated code looks like this:

```
function showStreetView(lat, lng)
{
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

/*  var panoramaOptions =
    {
        position: pos,
        pov: {
            heading: 0,
            pitch: 0
        }
    };
*/
    var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

    var STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE = 100;

    streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(pos, STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE, function(streetViewPanoramaData, status)
    {
        if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK)
        {
            var panoramaOptions =
            {
                position: streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng,  // here is the important change !!!!
                pov: {
                    heading: 0,
                    pitch: 0
                }
            };

            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('streetView'), panoramaOptions);

            map.setStreetView(panorama);
        }
        else
        {
            // no street view available in this range, or some error occurred
            map.getStreetView().setVisible(false);
        }
    });
}
```

So it was displaying 'grey' because I was trying to force it to display the panorama at the location I had calculated, rather that using the actual location of the panorama returned by the function in the third parameter of getPanoramaByLocation(...)

Comment: Yes, of course you need to find the nearest panorama location first and not just set it to some arbitrary lat lng position, but this wasn't the problem in my situation if you look at the code. The correct panorama location is fetched with getPanoramaByLocation before the streetmap is set visible. But the peoblem was that the location was not set when the streetmap was created for the first time as hidden component.