# Grey background for my streetview app

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-street-view

I'm trying to make my geolocation app work and after a lot of verification and console.log() functions, everything should work. My problem is that it doesn't actually work. I only have a grey background instead of the StreetView I want.

Here is the code :

```
StreetView: function (latitude, longitude) {
    $('#streetview').css({'width': $(window).width(), 'height': $(window).height()});

    var lookTo = {lat:  parseFloat(latitude), lng:  parseFloat(longitude)};
    var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latitude), parseFloat(longitude));
    var panoOptions = {
        position: lookTo,
        panControl: false,
        addressControl: false,
        linksControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: false
    };
    // initialize a new panorama API object and point to the element with ID streetview as container
    var pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('streetview'), panoOptions);
    // initialize a new streetviewService object
    var service = new google.maps.StreetViewService;
    // call the "getPanoramaByLocation" function of the Streetview Services to return the closest streetview position for the entered coordinates
    console.log('Pano Positon :'+ pano.getPosition());
    service.getPanoramaByLocation(pano.getPosition(), 50, function (panoData) {
        // if the function returned a result
        if (panoData != null) {
            // the GPS coordinates of the streetview camera position
            var panoCenter = panoData.location.latLng;
            console.log('PanoCenter' + panoCenter);
            // the "computeHeading" function calculates the heading with the two GPS coordinates entered as parameters
            var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(panoCenter, latlong);
            console.log('Heading : '+ heading);
            // now we know the heading (camera direction, elevation, zoom, etc) set this as parameters to the panorama object
            var pov = pano.getPov();
            pov.heading = heading;
            pano.setPov(pov);
            // set a marker on the location we are looking at, to verify the calculations were correct
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: pano,
                position: lookTo
            });
        } else {
            // no streetview found
            console.log('not found');
        }
    });

}
```

I copied a part of code I find about Google API and there were comments. So it should be readable.
If someone has an idea ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set zoom parameter. If this does not work, please be note that versions 3.20, 3.21, 3.22 are not available anymore as stated in this [forum](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9893&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal). Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions). If your browser is Internet Explorer, please ensure that you use [supported version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport) and do not use a compatibility mode.

Check these related questions:

- [Raising an exception for a grey streetview location in Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444229/raising-an-exception-for-a-grey-streetview-location-in-google-maps-javascript-ap)

> Use [`google.maps.StreetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#StreetViewService) to determine if there is a panorama available for the given location.

- [Google Maps API v3: Gray Box, no map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749742/google-maps-api-v3-gray-box-no-map)
- [Google Maps API v3 | shows no map data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273430/google-maps-api-v3-shows-no-map-data)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

Actually, I found what was wrong. I didn't have the Whitelist Plugin installed.

So the line : `<access origin='*' />` wasn't interpreted.
And I was calling this function (the StreetView function) after getting the Google Api script via $.getScript.
The Ajax call was never called beacause cross-domain requests weren't accepted.